# Is there a way to add proxy exceptions on Network Config?

Tags: settings

I can see I can set proxy's configuration for http, https, ftp, socks, etc. But I cannot set exceptions to this rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing a way to add proxy exceptions to network config. I would recommend editing the `/etc/environment` file manually.

Launch an editor to modify the environment file:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/environment
```

Add another line to the file for domains where you don't want to use a proxy by setting the `no_proxy` variable. For example:

```
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Comment: I had done this already, but was kinda wondering at what moment does this file gets read by the system.

Comment: @MarcelM. `/etc/environment` and the per-user equivalent `~/.pam_environment` are read when you log in.

Comment: Although it should work immediately, a reboot may sometimes(rarely though) be necessary to make it work.

Comment: FYI, I filed a bug to track this. I think it would be useful to add this to the graphical settings:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486785